# HTML/CSS - Image scaling using parent div

Tags: html, css

i'm new to stackoverflow.

I have zero experience with HTML or CSS, but i'm currently following some tutorials and find myself struggling to get an image to stay within the boundary of its parent div.

I have read all the topics I can find but none of the answers fix my issue? I must be doing something wrong.

Here is my CSS and HTML:

```css
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.title{
  border-style: solid;
}
.first_box{
  display:flex;
  max-height:500px;
  max-width:500px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.screenshot{
  max-height:50%;
  max-width:50%;
  border-style: solid;
}
.description{
  max-height: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <title>This is the website name.</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1 class="title">Major Header</h1>
 <div class="first_box">
  <img class="screenshot" src="Link.jpg" alt="Image of Toon Link">
  <div class="description">This is Toon Link. Yada Yada Yada. Text Text Text</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My intention was that the image would stay within aspect ratio but scale with the screen size upto the size of its container.
Instead, the height is much larger than the container and the image squashes horribly as the window size decreases.

I've figured that setting the image's max-height in pixels (rather than percent) will actually change the image height, but this still ignores the container size completely and is not responsive to window size.

I'm completely stumped?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Even if you are only beginnnig, maybe you've already heard of bootstrap ? It has some nice CSS/JS that lets you do things quickly. In your case, it would be enough to wrap your image in a [responsive embed](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed) div and a fluid layout.

Answer (score 0):

you maybe looking for ['max-height'](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp) and ['max-width'](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp). It helps to keep the aspect ratio.

Keep the `max-width` to the width of your container and `max-height` to the height of the container.

Answer (score 0):

you should try adding a control of dimensions inside html and body too.

for example you CSS will include:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

then

```
.first_box{
  height:50%;
  display:flex;
  max-height:500px;
  max-width:500px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.screenshot{
  height:50%;
  width:auto;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

This should improve a your layout, unfortunately the snippet can't show the image.